# Force occasionally being applied twice with OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a first person rocket jumping game, with the premise of shooting a rocket launcher at the players feet to move around.

I am having problems with my OnCollisionEnter function which stores all colliders in a radius and applies explosion force to them. When the player is completely on top of the explosion, force is being applied twice. Here is the code:

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
            Instantiate(explosionPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            Vector3 explosionPos = transform.position;
            //Use overlapshere to check for nearby colliders
            Collider[] collidersToDestroy = Physics.OverlapSphere(explosionPos, radius);
            foreach (Collider hit in collidersToDestroy)
            {
                //searches for what needs to be destroyed before applying force, this is for destructable objects
                Destructible dest = hit.GetComponent<Destructible>();
                if (dest != null)
                {
                    dest.DestroyWall();
                }
                ExplosiveBarrel barrel = hit.GetComponent<ExplosiveBarrel>();
                if (barrel != null)
                {
                    barrel.BarrelExplode();
                    
                }
            }
            
            Collider[] collidersToMove = Physics.OverlapSphere(explosionPos, radius);
            foreach (Collider hit in collidersToMove)
            {
                Rigidbody rb = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                //Add force to nearby rigidbodies
                if (rb != null)
                {
                    rb.AddExplosionForce(power * 5, explosionPos, radius, 3.0F);
                    if (hit.gameObject.tag == "Player")
                    {
                        //if player is hit
                        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Hit");
                        

                    }
                }

                Destroy(gameObject);
            }


        }
        
    }
```

I can tell the force is being applied twice to the player by using UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Hit"); , which appears twice in the console. Furthermore, I am pretty sure this is happening on the same frame, as putting Destroy(gameObject); within the if (player hit) statement yields the same results.

This only occurs when the player is right next to the explosion, if the player is a small distance away the force is only applied once. I would very much like to solve this problem and have the force only applied once.

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Well you have two loops applying forces .. is it possible you land in both loops for the same object?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The first loop just searches for specific colliders in the radius and then calls a function, like an explosive barrel or a wall to be destroyed. I have tried commenting out the first loop anyway, and the problem still persists.

Comment: Btw you should probably call `Destroy` only once anyway and not inside the loop?

Comment: Also is it possible that this `explosionPrefab` you instantiate adds some force itself?

Comment: And also .. is this question related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384053/unity-2d-rigidbody2d-addexplosionforce-problems/65384752)?

Comment: Why do you need two loops? Your calls to ```OverlapSphere``` both use the same parameters.  Just do one call and one iteration.  What does ```ExplosiveBarrel.BarrelExplode()``` do?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I've checked the explosionPrefab, and it does not add force. However, the explosionPrefab is visible in the hierarchy before being despawned, when the force is applied twice, I can see 2 explosionPrefabs in the hierarchy. I think this means that it isn't a problem with the loops, but the OnCollisionEnter function being called twice, as the explosionPrefab is instantiated outside of the loops. Not sure where to go from here though.

Comment: Immersive: The first loop is used mainly for my destructible walls. The walls are made destructible by instantiating a fractured version of the wall after being hit. The second loop is used so force is also applied to the new fractured version of the wall. The barrel explosion function just calls a function to explode a barrel when a barrel is within the radius of the explosion, as I don't want force to applied to the actual barrel rigidbody.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it!
OnCollisionEnter was being called twice because I had two colliders perfectly stacked on one another, so the projectile was hitting the 2 colliders on the same time step.

Comment: This! I had projectile sometimes hitting the seam between 2 modular walls, thus entering 2 colliders at the same time.